# SharePoint newListItem Soap with img attachment

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, sharepoint, soap

I have a function in my Apache Cordova application to create a new list item inside a sharepoint list, and I was wondering if it was possible to add an image to this new item, this would come as an 'attachment' in the sharepoint list. My function to add a new item looks like this:

```
function CreateItem(Title, Description) { 
var soapEnv =          
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +         
"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +          
"xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +      
"<soapenv:Body>" +                           
"<UpdateListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">" +     
"<listName>LISTNAME</listName>" +                
"<updates>" +                          
"<Batch OnError=\"Continue\">" +           
"<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\">" +            
"<Field Name=\"ID\">New</Field>" +            
"<Field Name=\"Title\">" + Title + "</Field>" +
"<Field Name=\"Description\">" + Description + "</Field>" + 
"</Method>" +   
"</Batch>" +                         
"</updates>" +                        
"</UpdateListItems>" +               
"</soapenv:Body>" +                  
"</soapenv:Envelope>";               
$.ajax({     
url: "URL",
type: "POST",                           
dataType: "xml",                        
data: soapEnv,                         
beforeSend: function (xhr) {             
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",           
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"); 
},                           
complete: processCreateResultSuccess,    
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",    
error: processCreateResultError             
});
```

}

The image is taken with the Cordova app and has the ID "image". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SharePoint: AddAttachment SOAP Web Service

Yes, you can use SharePoint SOAP web services to upload an image attachment to a list. However, there are some limitations.

My demo below uses the [AddAttachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd774485(v=office.12).aspx) action of the [Lists web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313068%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The required parameters are listed and can be modified for your own environment. The demo simply adds a text file attachment, but it works with images and other file types too. Also works with SP 2007-2013.

The limitation is that files must be encoded as base-64 for transfer within the SOAP envelope. On the client side, base-64 file encoding is not a trivial task. I've done it using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object, but that is only available in modern browsers (IE10). There might be other options with mobile devices, but I've not researched it. Alternatively, you might look at the newer [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx).

```
<html>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function addAttachment(  ) {

    var webUrl = '',                     // base url when list in sub site
        listName = 'CustomList',         // list name or guid 
        listItemID = '1',                // list item id
        fileName = 'HelloWorld.txt',     // file name 
        attachment = 'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=', // base-64 encode file data "Hello Word!"
        xhr, soap;

    soap = (
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<soap:Envelope '+
                'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '+
            'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '+
            'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
            '<soap:Body>'+
                '<AddAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">'+
                    '<listName>' + listName + '</listName>'+
                    '<listItemID>' + listItemID + '</listItemID>'+
                    '<fileName>' + fileName + '</fileName>'+
                    '<attachment>' + attachment + '</attachment>'+
                '</AddAttachment>'+
            '</soap:Body>'+
        '</soap:Envelope>'
    );

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', webUrl + '/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx', true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddAttachment');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        // do something - returns file path or error message
        console.info( xhr.status + '\n' + xhr.responseText );
    }
    xhr.send( soap );

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you man, I've been at this for a while, and you cleared it up for me ;)